# Changing items properties in MapItemsControl.ItemsSource

Tags: windows-phone-7, data-binding, dictionary, windows-phone-8

I have `MapItemsControl`, `Pushpins` and Data-binding:

```
 <toolkit:MapItemsControl>
                    <toolkit:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <toolkit:Pushpin GeoCoordinate="{Binding Coordinate}" 
                                             Content="{Binding ContentPushpin}"
                                             Background="{Binding Background}"  
                                             Tag="{Binding Tag}"   
                                             Tap="userPushpin_Tap"                                                
                                             >                                      
                             </toolkit:Pushpin>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </toolkit:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>                        
                </toolkit:MapItemsControl>
```

Binding pushpins to `MapItemsControl`:

```
ObservableCollection<MyPushpin> PushpinsCollections = ObservableCollection<MyPushpin>();

PushpinsCollections.Add(new MyPushpin()
{
   Coordinate = ....,
   Id = ... 
   //init other properties
});

NokiaMapItemsControl.ItemsSource = PushpinsCollections;
```

Next, one of the `Pushpin` changed the coordinates, I can find it in the collection by a unique ID. But how can I change his position that these changes appear on the map, without redrawing the other pushpins?

Comment: Have you tried removing the old pushpin from `PushpinsCollections`, creating a new one with the right coordinates, then adding it to that same collection?

Comment: Implement InotifyPropertyChanged Interface in MyPushpin and raise property changed event for "Coordinate" Property. It will update that pin only.

Comment: Thanks all! Yeah really, necessary implement InotifyPropertyChanged Interface.